# Metadata Types whose components can be a lot

Tags: metadata-api, metadata, list-metadata

As part of our Metadata related product, we are trying to re-design our apis to handle metadata list efficiently, especially considering some large enterprise customers.

As part of that exercise, we want to separate Metadata Types which typically have lots of components into separate api and keep rest as part of main APIs. We identified following types which can result in large components. Do you have any thoughts on this list or suggest any other types that should belong to this list?

```
Dashboard
Document
EmailTemplate
Report
Role
```

Comment: Do you include content documents, versions and the like under Document? Could you give a bit more context around what you mean by "efficient"? Are you thinking about maximum request/response size limits, for example?

Comment: ContentVersion are not Metadata but data. This question is more from context of a product that helps with Metadata deployment. When customers wants to select  components for deployments, we are right now  list all components. For some customers this could be upto 250K  or 300K  entries. Majority  of them are of type  listed in question. So I'm  asking if there are other metadata types that tend  to have lots of them in a org.

Comment: This question seems somewhat opinion based and entirely dependent on what orgs you have access to.

Comment: Talking about opinions, mine is that customers could benefit from adopting the use of unlocked packages to deal with deployment all the way up to test and production... I personally don't see the sense in deploying individual metadata items since it becomes difficult to track exactly what is on which org. There is no source of truth in this context.

Comment: Question is not asking about opinion but fact about which component type they  seen in their org having lots of components in them. While possible that one customer to create 10k of RemoteSiteSetting type but it is very unlikely but possible that one could create lots of reports.